# Generate Lambda Expression

Tags: vb.net, lambda, expression

Supossedly, I have the code below:

```
Public Class Fruit
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Function GetName() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class
```

```
Dim list As New List(Of Fruit)

For index = 1 To 10
    Dim fruitObj As New Fruit
    fruitObj.Name = "Testing" + index.ToString()
    list.Add(fruitObj)
Next

Dim iEnumerableString As IEnumerable(Of String) = list.Select(Function(m) m.Name)
```

At the code sample above, If I would like to generate `Function(m) m.Name`, how should I do it?

So that, I could call it as below:

```
Dim iEnumerableString As IEnumerable(Of String) =
list.Select(GenerateLambda("name"))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create expression tree with your parameter call.

`GeneratePropertyExpression` method:

```
Private Shared Function GeneratePropertyExpression(Of TSource, TResult)(propertyName As String) As Func(Of TSource, TResult)
    Dim parameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(TSource), "x")
    Dim propertyExpression = Expression.[Property](parameter, propertyName)
    Return Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of TSource, TResult))(propertyExpression, parameter).Compile()
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim iEnumerableString As IEnumerable(Of String) = list.Select(GeneratePropertyExpression(Of Fruit, String)("Name"))
```

I haven't tested that, so let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Cool. You should now spend some time trying to understand what's happening there (if you haven't done that already). That's the best way to learn new language features. :)